# How to calculate the number of empty bucket when aggregating by days?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I want to get the number of days that a person stayed in a town in May (`Month` equal to 5).

This is my query, but it gives me the number of entries in `myindex` that have `PersonID` equal to `111` and `Month` equal to 5. For example, this query may give me an output like 90, but there are maximally 31 days per month.

```
GET myindex/_search?
{
 "size":0,
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": {
          "PersonID": "111"
        }},
        { "match": {
          "Month": "5"
        }}
      ]
    } },
   "aggs": {
    "stay_days": {
     "terms" : {
      "field": "Month"
     }
    }
   }
}
```

In `myindex` I have fields like `DateTime` with the date and time when a person was registered by a camera, e.g. `2017-05-01T00:30:08"`. So, during a single day the same person may pass several times by the camera, but it should be count as 1.

How can I update my query in order to calculate the number of days per month instead of the number of capturing by a camera?

Comment: Can you provide your mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `DateTime` field called `datetime`, one way to consider is [DateHistogram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) aggregation:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "PersonID": "111"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "datetime": {
              "gte": "2017-05-01",
              "lt": "2017-06-01"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "my_day_histogram": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "datetime",
        "interval": "1d",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- Pay attention, that, in the `must` clause I used [range](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) term with the `datetime` field (not necessary but you may consider the `Month` field redundant). Also, you may need to edit the date format in the range term to your mapping
- **my_day_histogram**: divide the data to buckets of separate days by setting the `"interval": "1d"`.
- `"min_doc_count": 1` removes buckets contains zero documents.

Other approach, remove the range/match for month 5 and extend the histogram for every day in the year.
This can be also aggregated with month histogram like so:

```
  "aggregations": {
    "my_month_histogram": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "first_timestamp",
        "interval": "1M",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "my_day_histogram": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "first_timestamp",
            "interval": "1d"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Its clear to me that, in both ways you'll need to count the number of buckets for which indicates the number of days.